# One logger for a multi-project solution

Tags: serilog

I am integrating Serilog into an existing multi-class layer and Multi-Assembly Solution that I've created. The previous logging technique I used was simply passing a string up the layers with events. I'd like to get away from this.

I have read that I can use the app.config file to load the logger config into each class in my library but how can I do this in a multi-assembly project.

I have a top-level / startup project and two class library projects. I would like to use the same logger with two sinks for the whole program.

These are the articles I have found so far

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings

http://nblumhardt.com/2014/04/xml-configuration-for-serilog/

Could someone explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: can you please share your solution for this question? I have exact same requirements for my project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Serilog lets you use a logger configuration per program; though it's possible to adjust logging class-by-class this is usually done after the fact with filtering and so-on.

The recommended approach is:

Set up Serilog as the first thing in `Program.Main()` or wherever your app's entry point is:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.Sink1()
  .WriteTo.Sink2()
  .CreateLogger();
```

Notice this sets up the static `Log` class. Elsewhere in your app you can now write:

```
Log.Information("This is a message");
```

and the message will be passed to both sinks. You can avoid the static `Log` and instead pass `ILogger` around, but unless you have strong preferences here, the static option is less hassle.

XML/`appSettings` configuration doesn't change any of this. It just moves some details to the config file, so changing the first block of code to:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
  .CreateLogger();
```

And adding:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Sink1" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Sink2" />
```

to `App.config` will have the same effect. Configuration in code is often less hassle (fewer moving parts) if you can avoid the XML.

Comment: I'm trying to do as you described. The Serilog setup is done on the main Core project. Then a reference to Serilog package was added also to Web API project, where inside Controllers I added a direct reference to Log object (`Log.Information("This is a message");`) to write on configured sinks (Console and SQLServer). When I hit the line inside Core classes, everything works just fine, while from Controllers I've no errors but no logs too.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my solution to multi-assembly logging:

I set up the Mainlogger with the configuration as usual in the master assembly, i.e. the assembly responsible for creating and configuring the log. In my case the logging-master is a GUI application which interacts with a dll, which acutally does the work.

Then I installed Serilog in the slave-assembly and exposed a subscribe function to the master assembly like this:

```
void SubscribeLogging(ILogger masterlogger)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
          .WriteTo.Logger(masterlogger)
          .CreateLogger();
}
```

which i than call from the master assembly if necessary

```
myDll.SubscribeLogging(Log.ForContext("SourceContext", "myDll"));
```

As far as I can tell, one could manipulate the logging configuration to a certain degree, but I did not try using a completely different output template in the slave assemply.